# Effektif versus Activiti

Tags: jbpm, activiti, business-process-management, bpmn

What are the differences between Effektif and Activiti besides the obvious cloud-based support? Would I be able to port my Activiti processes/project to Effektif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tough question and even though both projects were originated by the same fellow (Tom Baeyens) they have take quite a different focus to cloud based process modeling.

Similarities:

1. Both Activiti and Effektif are lightweight, embeddable BPMN compatible workflow engines
2. Both projects are sponsored by a parent company (Alfresco in the case of Activiti, Signavio in the case of Effektif)
3. Both projects are released under the Apache 2.0 license
4. Both engines cite their strengths in light weight and embed ability.
5. Both backends are written in Java

Differences:

1. Activiti is a relatively mature project with many contributors (including myself and others from Bp3). Effektif (the engine itself) is still in Beta (or maybe even alpha release).
2. Activiti (currently) uses one of a number of supported RDBMS database as the system repository where Effectif uses a noSQL backing database (mongo).
3. Activiti has a very vibrant support structure through both Alfresco hosted and stackoverflow forums. Effectif support, while still good, is not as broad.
4. Alfresco have and are making a significant commitment of resources to attempt to make Activiti (the enterprise edition) competitive with other commercial and open source offerings. I am not certain Signavio have the same level of commitment to Effektif (this is a personal opinion only).

Either way, in the right environment I expect both engines will be more than capable of satisfying your needs.